# Flutter Bloc - Widget tree growing endlessy

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

When I'm going back from the final view to my "initial view" every `State` of all 3 `BlocProviders` is being saved.

See Widget tree:
[image: Widget Tree]

My Code is linked here:
[GIST](https://gist.github.com/skvie/467ab9eeccb93d949a31788b402a1f75)

I don't understand what I am missing, on first run everything works fine.

However, when I go back to `InitialView` when I'm in `GameView`, set everything up again and move to the GameModeSelectionView again, its getting called multiple times (States are somehow saved instead of dumped??)*(1)*:

```
flutter: State of GameSelectionState GameSelectionInitial
flutter: State of GameSelectionState GameSelectionStart
flutter: State of QuestionState StopQuestion
flutter: OK?
flutter: State of GameSelectionState GameSelectionStart
flutter: State of QuestionState StopQuestion
flutter: OK?
flutter: State of GameSelectionState GameSelectionStart
flutter: State of QuestionState StopQuestion
flutter: OK?
flutter: State of GameSelectionState GameSelectionInitial
```

This process grows with each iteration *(1)*

I am using the flutter_bloc dependency:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using `MaterialPageRoute` `onGenerateRoute` (since I need to route dynamically)

I replaced the code in my Buttons `onPressed` method to like:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
              GameModeSelectionView.routeName,
              arguments: players);
```

Works like a charm and no more growing tree.